# Salesforce1 Admin app simulator giving URL No Longer Exists

Tags: salesforce1-app

Trying to invoke the emulator for Admin app on Salesforce.

Is this working for you after Spring 15 release ? Looks like it is broken.

I am getting **URL no longer exist** and takes me to Full Site

Comment: what is the url you are trying to access?

Comment: using login.salesforce.com/one/admin.app

Comment: what emulator ?

Comment: To access SF1 without mobile device

Comment: Do you mean the Saleforce1 Simulator Chrome plugin?

Comment: @prax if your aim is to access SF1 without a mobile device all you need is https:// yourinstance.salesforce.com/one/one.app. I was not able to access the one/admin.app extension provided by you( it seems undocumented feature atleast to me, I could be wrong).

Comment: Here is what you would do to quickly test apps without the mobile device - No plugins required

1. login in to your Salesforce instance in one tab (login.salesforce.com)

2. Open Salesforce in another tab using (login.salesforce.com/one/one.app) URL - This will simulate & show SalesForce1 app  (if enabled) - This works for me.

3. Open third tab using (login.salesforce.com/one/admin.app) URL- This should simulate & show SalesForceA App for Admins

I am saying this is broken and takes you to full site with a msg 'URL is no longer exist' 


Hope this makes sense.

Comment: @prax I see the same "url no longer exists" message with one/admin.app

Comment: thanks for checking - that confirms the fact it is broken and gives generic mesage.